# ArgumentError for very simple "initialize" method in Ruby on Rails with no arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the simplest possible Ruby on Rails class:

```
class ProductProperty < ApplicationRecord
  def initialize
    puts 'hello world'
  end
end
```

But when I simply try to instantiate it, I get an ArgumentError:

```
[1] pry(main)> ProductProperty.new
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

I'm unclear why it thinks I am passing an argument in ("`given 1`"). Do I need to do something else to be able to write an `initialize` method that doesn't take arguments?

Comment: why do you have an **initialize** in a rails model?

Comment: @Haumer - Small part of larger goal. I am hoping to create `attr_accessor`s in the `initialize` method based on an array that I can store elsewhere. Open to suggestions if you can think of another way to create `attr_accessor`s based on a class or instance method.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something *before, during* or *after* you create/initalize an object you can use [callbacks](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#available-callbacks)

For example:

```rb
class ProductProperty < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :do_something_special

  def do_something_special
    puts "I'm doing something"
  end
end
ProductProperty.create #=> "I'm doing something"
```

there are more callbacks available, so you can call specific methods during the lifecycle of an object.

you might also want to check out [active record migrations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) if you want to persist and change data in your database

Comment: Got it, thanks. I forgot about the `after_initialize` callback. I needed this to happen when I called `.new` on the object, well before any of the callbacks related to writing to the database. ( https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#after-initialize-and-after-find )

Comment: _"you should probably not define your own initialize method in a rails model"_ – any official reference for that or an explanation on _why_ this doesn't work or isn't recommended? It seems to be a quite fundamental limitation.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `*args`.

```rb
class ProductProperty < ApplicationRecord
  def initialize(*args)
    puts 'hello world'
  end
end
```

But I am wondering why you override initialize?
You can use [active record callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html) for that.